# append image from files browser to selected image texture node by just one or double click

Tags: node-editor, file-browser

[image]

how can i append image from files browser to selected image texture node by just one or double click (without dragging it from file browser region to shader node editor region)?

Comment: Hello :). Why not just use the **[ Open ]** button in the node? That will open a new file browser.

Comment: For quick and direct access to files without repeating the process of opening the file more than once. I try to adjust the user interface and settings in Blender so that it facilitates new users, especially novice ones, to deal with Blender, as well as the same for users who have moved from other programs such as substance painter, I see that Blender is not much different from substance painter as many people think, and in order to prove this, I configure Blender in various ways such as using ready-made addons and also writing python script  even though I am a beginner in programming

Comment: I want to do this from the file browser region that is already in my user interface without opening a new file browser window